# Loading dynamic components based on user input in angular 5+

Tags: angular, dynamic, components

I have an application where a user makes a decision on one page (I'm using cdk stepper), when they get to the next page, I want to dynamically load different components based on what the user selected.

Think of the choices as different form components, and the next page will display one to many of these based on those choices.  I don't want to just use ngIf in the html because there will potentially 100+ of these forms, so I want each selection a user makes to have a variable (metadata) associated with it, which can be used to dynamically load any number of components on the next screen.

I looked at CDK Portal for this but I'm wondering if there's a better solution.  If there isn't, I'm not 100% sure on how CDK Portal would work for this, every form I think would have to extend some base component.  I believe the typescript would be set up to load the components into the portal host.  Let me know if anyone has suggestions or questions on this.

Comment: whether the components created dynamically or already created?

Comment: the components already exist, it's just a question of how to I display 1 to many of them on the screen at the same time based on user selection

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you still need to put the if/else logic elsewhere to make it work. My first approach to this problem is to make a table of selection components with two columns, component's name, and a Boolean to know it is selected:

```
[(A, false), (B, false)]
```

You still need to put every components for next step into HTML file, like this:

```
<a *ngIf="isComponentSelection(a)"></a>
<b *ngIf="isComponentSelection(b)"></b>
```

The logic inside `isComponentSelection` is to know this component should be displayed or not, it will check with the table we made above.

In the first board, you just need to bind into the table a list of checkbox with the name of components you have.

Comment: So the way I'm thinking about it, each of the forms they can possibly select has an ID, that ID has some metadata associated with it.  if they select forms D, L, and Q, I would look that up and find D.componentName, L.componentName, and Q.component name.  This would prevent me from having to use any if/else logic if I could then say, for each component in selectedComponentList, show component.componentName.

Comment: that is the idea of using the table, if you have more than 100 components like you said, you can look up in the table faster, the boolean is just a flag to tell you should activate the component. Usually, it is rarely to have more than 100 different form components, you should divide it and choose what actually different and keep the other the same

Comment: the end state is to have over 100, so my concern is how maintainable this solution would be.  I think for the most part what each form is trying to accomplish will be different enough to warrant their own form.

Comment: you should separate it at first and see what it needs to accomplish, make a core form part and add only the different